# Исправление ошибок реестра

Tags: windows, администрирование, реестр

Здравствуйте! Посоветуйте, как быть? Поставили задачу ежедневно чистить реестр (устранять ошибки) на машинах пользователей. Есть ли для этого специальные инструменты или придется устанавливать ПО на каждую машину? С такими программами раньше сталкиваться не приходилось. Основные требования: работа в фоновом режиме, безопасность использования для системы.

Answer (score 1):

На правильно настроенной ОС с правильно настроенными учетками пользователей выполнять такую задачу нет никакой необходимости. Более того, использование всяких чистильщиков и оптимизаторов может привести к нарушению стабильности работы системы.

Категорически рекомендую спрыгнуть с этой задачи, поскольку ничего хорошего от ее реализации не будет.

Comment: Учётками в домене мы не рулим, можем задавать только локальные политики для каждой машины. Так что как есть так и приходится разгребать. Собственно, на другом форуме мне тоже сказали, что нет такой необходимости. Так что и я все больше в этом убеждаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Auslogics_BoostSpeed_4.5.14.260+key

http://narod.ru/disk/63239457001.d0dcfffff8edabffabd13ab255712899/Auslogics_BoostSpeed_4.5.14.260%2Bkey.rar.html

Comment: глянул ради интереса, но +key у нас не пройдёт.

Comment: У нас с Каспером проходит